# PHP PDO and IN clause

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a statement being used with PDO which is as follows:

```
$stmt = _DB::init()->prepare("SELECT a.*
                              FROM tax_class a
                              INNER JOIN products_to_tax_class pa 
                              ON a.tid = pa.tid
                              WHERE pa.pid IN (1,2)
                             ");
```

Now the statement gets executed, however it only grabs results for `pa.pid = 2`, or the last value of the ones given. Would anyone be able to explain this for me? I was expecting an array of results from both `id's 1 and 2` however this only outputs `Array ( [tid] => 2 [rate] => 7.30 [name] => Something )`

```
if ($stmt->execute())
          return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$stmt->fetch` only fetches one row at a time.  Use [fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) to return the entire result set

Comment: You rock! (As you can see I'm new to PDO)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're only calling `fetch` once. This means you're getting the first row from the query and no more.

Try:

```
$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```